# Kibana Visualize Customize

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-5

Can we customize **kibana** visualize apart from label and color in **kibana 5.5.1**

Need to achieve customization on my dashboard:

[image]

Comment: what kind of customizations you want ? Have you looked into this - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/timelion-customize.html

Comment: @Aky_0788 I have added [Visualize link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqkAQ.jpg)

Comment: i am afraid that kind of customization is not possible.

Comment: @aky_0788 Is there any other way to do that ?

Comment: kibana does not has this kind of support. Not sure about other visualization tools.